# How to login to wikidata with pywikibot

Tags: python, wikidata, pywikibot

I am trying to access data from wikidata using pywikibot. I am trying to do this with the name of the data object and not the code. 
When I run this script:

```
import pywikibot


site = pywikibot.Site("wikidata", "wikidata")
repo = site.data_repository()
token = repo.token(pywikibot.Page(repo, 'Main Page'), 'edit')
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/this-user/PycharmProjects/teststuff/src/pywikibot_stuff/wikipedia/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    token = repo.token(pywikibot.Page(repo, 'Main Page'), 'edit')
  File "/Users/this-user/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pywikibot/tools/__init__.py", line 1337, in wrapper
    return obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/this-user/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pywikibot/site.py", line 3495, in token
<class 'AssertionError'>
    return self.tokens[tokentype]
  File "/Users/this-user/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pywikibot/site.py", line 1785, in __getitem__
    assert self.site.user(), 'User must login in this site'
AssertionError: User must login in this site
CRITICAL: Closing network session.
```

However, this is confusing to me, because when I run the following script (Q9684 is the wikidata code for the New York Times):

```
import pywikibot

site = pywikibot.Site('wikidata', 'wikidata')
repo = site.data_repository()
item = pywikibot.ItemPage(repo, 'Q9684')

item_dict = item.get()
aliases = item_dict['aliases']
aliases = [aliases[key] for key in aliases]
aliases = [alias for sublist in aliases for alias in sublist]


print(aliases
```

Everything works fine and I get:

```
['NY Times', 'New York Times', 'The Gray Lady', 'Gray Lady', 'NYT', 'TNYT', 'nytimes.com', 'New-York Daily Times', 'The New-York Times', 'NY Times', 'NY Times', 'New York Times', 'New York Times', 'NYT', 'NY Times', 'NY Times', 'New York Times', 'The Gray Lady', 'Gray Lady', 'The Grey Lady', 'Grey Lady', 'New York Times', 'NYT', '紐約時報', 'nytimes.com', 'New York Times', 'The New York Daily Times', 'NY Times', 'New York Times', 'NYT', 'The Gray Lady', 'The New York Times', 'Нью-Йорк Таймс', 'NY Times', 'New York Times', 'NYT', 'نيو يورك تايمز']
```

I have also tried running:

```
import pywikibot

site = pywikibot.Site('wikidata', 'wikidata')
repo = site.data_repository()
item = pywikibot.Page(site, 'New York Times')
item_dict = item.get()

print(item_dict)
```

But then I get the error:

```
pywikibot.exceptions.NoPage: Page [[wikidata:New York Times]] doesn't exist.
```

My user-config.py file is in the same directory and looks like this:

```
family = 'wikidata'
mylang = 'en'
usernames['wikidata']['wikidata'] = u'ExampleBot'

#console_encoding = 'utf-8'
#use_api_login = True
```

Uncommenting the last 2 lines doesn't make a difference.

Does anybody know the problem here? Why does pywikibot want me to log in when I search for 'New York Times' but not when I use the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The titles of pages of items in wikidata are their 'Q' id. Therefore

```
item = pywikibot.Page(site, 'New York Times')
```

creates a page that does not exist:

```
>>> item.exists()
False
```

and item.get() fails for wikidata site.
You have to run:

```
item = pywikibot.Page(site, 'Q9684')
```

token is taken in order to edit things in the repository not just retrieving and for that you need to be logged in.

Answer (score 1):

> But then I get the error:

```
pywikibot.exceptions.NoPage: Page [[wikidata:New York Times]] doesn't exist.
```

This occurs because in Wikidata main namespace really does not exist a page named "New York Times". If you know exact Wikipedia page title(s), and if you want to get their Wikidata item ID, you can do this so:

```
wpsite = pywikibot.Site('en', 'wikipedia')
wppage = pywikibot.Page(wpsite, 'The New York Times')
item = pywikibot.ItemPage.fromPage(wppage)
```

instead of:

```
item = pywikibot.Page(site, 'New York Times') # this is wrong
```

And actually you'll not need the line with *token = repo.token...* to edit Wikidata if you'll use the framework functions.
See more details [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/Wikidata) and accessing the page links listed at the bottom of that page.